# Updating JAVA_HOME using a bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash scripting thus the question,
I've a function which install java in a system and updates the path in bashrc.

```
install_java(){
  echo "Installing Java 8 & 11 and setting JAVA_HOME to 8"
  brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
  echo "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home"
}
```

I want to update the hardcoded version string with the output of java -version
This is my output of java -version

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Can someone help me extract the version number from the first line an substitute it for the version number in the JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: Did the following answer helped you in any way to resolve your question ? If it does, can you please accept the answer, if it does not helped, please provide more info for imporvement.

Answer (score 1):

Here java version is parsed using `java -version|grep -oP 'java version\s"\K[^"]+'` and stored in `java_ver` variable and later substituted in `JAVA_HOME` assignment.

```
install_java(){
  echo "Installing Java 8 & 11 and setting JAVA_HOME to 8"   
  brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
  java_ver=$(java -version 2>&1|grep -oP 'version\s"\K[^"]+')
  echo "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk${java_ver}.jdk/Contents/Home"
}
```

Explanation of `java -version 2>&1|grep -oP 'version\s"\K[^"]+'`:

`grep -o`: this will only extract the matching content not the matching line, `-P` flag enable `PCRE`, now the regex is java version followed be space(`\s`) then followed by `"` till next `"` is seen. Also, ignore anything on the left of `\K`.

***If you do not have `-P` enabled on your grep then you can use `awk` command:***

```
install_java(){
  echo "Installing Java 8 & 11 and setting JAVA_HOME to 8"   
  brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
  brew cask install adoptopenjdk11
  java_ver=$(java -version 2>&1|awk '/version/{gsub(/"/,"",$NF);print $NF}')
  echo "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk${java_ver}.jdk/Contents/Home"
}
```

Comment: I did `echo $java_ver` and it's an empty string

Comment: can you run `java -version|grep -oP 'java version\s"\K[^"]+'` on your terminal ?

Comment: Replace `java -version` with `java -version 2>&1`.

Comment: @MelissaStewart , updated the answer, please retry, Reason,  `java -version` print to stderr, and to pipe it to `grep` we need to convert to stdout using `2>&1` after the commands.

Comment: This also doesn't work, `java_ver=$(java -version 2>&1|grep -oP 'java version\s"\K[^"]+')`

Comment: Replace `java version` with `version`.

Comment: you may be using `openjdk` that could be causing mismatch, as @cyrus pointed use just `version` not `java version` like `java -version 2>&1|grep -oP 'version\s"\K[^"]+')`

Comment: This is what I get,
`java_ver=$(java -version 2>&1|grep -oP 'version\s"\K[^"]+')
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: try `java -version 2>&1 |awk '/version/{gsub(/"/,"",$NF);print $NF}'` as you do not have `-P` flag supported on your grep , so use awk command